# Find all answers that are the same

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a List of peoples' answer to a questionnaire.  The answers are currently an array of strings so my object looks like

```
 List<string[]> answers = new List<string[]>() 
 { new string[]{"T","A","T","F","B"},
   new string[]{"F","A","T","F","B"},
   new string[]{"T","A","F","F","B"}
 };
```

I need to find those array indexes and values where all the values are the same.
The resulting object can either be  `string[]` like

```
 {"","A","","F","B"}
```

or some type of custom object tuple that would be like {1,"A"}, {3, "F"}, {4, "B"}

I can assume that all string arrays will be of the same length.

I can do this through brute force and loops but I was wondering if there was a more efficient cleaner way, possibly through Linq.

Which begs the question, does Linq just use loops internally and the only efficiency your saving is lines of code and having to create local variables.

**Update:**
Going off of what  O. R. Mapper and Vajura 
I was thinking of two loops

Get the first set of answers, that gives me the length of each string[] and gives me what the answer should be.  Even if the first person is the only one that answered A then all other non-A would automatically disqualify that index

```
for each index in string[]
    answer = List[0][index]
    for i=1 to List.Count - 1 
        compare answer to List[i][index]
        if false exit loop

    if we made it through it is good
```

Comment: **Linq** is *syntactical sugar*, and when compiled to IL will use loops etc under the hood.

Comment: Using *loops* does not mean using *brute force*. And, yes, LINQ just uses loops internally and thus there is no inherent gain in execution efficiency compared to properly written loops.

Comment: There is no other way then "brute force" for this solution. You need to check every value. That being said you can optimize it a lot lets say that the first index of your second string array is already difrent then the first then you dont need to check that value anymore for any succeding array. There are probably other small things where you can optimize it.

Comment: @Vajura two different Linq methods have been given, so I would not say that "brute force" is the ONLY way.  It may the the BEST way, but certainly not the ONLY way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
answers
.SelectMany(x => x.Select((y, idx) => new { c = y, index = idx })) // 1
.GroupBy(x => x) // 2
.Where(x => x.Count() == answers.Count) // 3
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.index, x => x.Key.c); // 4
```

Here is the working [`fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ShQbCI)

The explanation would be:

1. Flatten the list and select each letter and it's index into an anonymous type
2. Group the pairs by letter and the index (anonymous types compared based on property values so we are grouping by letter and the index at the same time)
3. This is the tricky part, get those groups that has `answer.Count` many items, so we make sure that letter-index pair exists in all inner arrays in other words: a letter present at the same index in all arrays.
4. Finally put the groups into a dictionary where the Keys are indexes and the Values are letters.

Comment: Thank you for the break down.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to say you *can*, here's a Linq method:

```
var results = answers.Aggregate(answers[0],(p, n) => p.Zip(n, (pi, ni) => pi==ni ? pi : "")
                                                      .ToArray())
                     .ToArray();
```

although IF you decide to use this in a real app I would CLEARLY document how it works and what the result means.

In reality this will be no more efficient than a properly designed loop, and code readability is more important that brevity, all other things being equal.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way in LinQ:

```
string[] result = answers
      .Aggregate((a, b) => 
      a.Select(a1 => (b[Array.IndexOf(a,a1)] == a1) ? a1 : "").ToArray());
```

If you care about performance, I recommend you to use `for` loops on an array, because they are 5 time faster than doing a `foreach` on a List (and a lot faster than Linq too). There are some articles about it, but I found [this](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances/) pretty interesting. On the other hand, Linq is more readable and elegant (ok, that's just my opinion), so if your arrays are not too long or you don't care about performance, I recommend you this Linq method.